# Can I use my external hard drive while it's being encrypted using BitLocker?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker

I'm encrypting my external hard drive using BitLocker. The process will take some hours. Can I use it while it's being encrypted? Is it safe? Or will the data that I move to it being unencrypted because the encryption process isn't done yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe to use. All the data will eventually be encrypted. However, using the drive will slow down the encryption and make it take longer to complete.

Comment: And using the drive is slower than normal because the encrypting is running. Can be so slow the disk is effectively unusable until BitLocker is done.

Answer (score 0):

As Keltari already said this is safe.

What happens is the following:

BitLocker inserts its encrypting/de-encryptng engine in the normal disk-IO driver so it can intercept anything written/read to/from the disk.
From that point on any block that gets written to the disk is encrypted on the fly. And any block read is de-crypted (if needed). So from the users perspective the encryption is transparent.

Then the first-time encryption program simply reads every block that is not yet encrypted and writes it back (which automatically encrypts it).
So any new data you write after the encryption is started is encrypted immediately. Any existing data gets encrypted eventually by the first-time encryption program.

Using a disk while it is undergoing this first-time encryption is perfectly safe. It will just be slow because of the heavy disk-IO that is going on.
You can reboot the machine if needed.

In case of external media you can even temporarily remove the media if you want (be VERY SURE to do a safe eject in that case!!!). You can even plug the BitLocker disk in another computer that also has BitLocker and the disk can be used and the first-time encryption process will continue on that other computer (if you provide the correct password obviously).